# Getting error of getaccountname doesn't exist while backing up database

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to restore my MYSQL 5.7 database from .sql dump file with the following command:

> mysql -h hostname -u username -p databasename < backup.sql

But, I am getting the following error:

> ROR 1305 (42000) at line 5940: FUNCTION dbtable.getaccountname does
>   not exist

The line 5940 of .sql file contains the following:

> /*!50001 VIEW `vloantransaction` AS select
>   `loantransaction`.`transactionid` AS
>   `transactionid`,`loantransaction`.`bookingdatenp` AS
>   `bookingdatenp`,`loantransaction`.`accountnumber` AS `accountnumber`,
>   getaccountname(`loantransaction`.`accountnumber`,'a') AS
>   `accname`,getaccountname (`loantransaction`.`accountnumber`,'h')

Comment: Sounds like you created the dump without using the `mysqldump --routines` option, so the dump didn't include stored functions. If you can't create a new dump from the original database, I hope you have the code for your stored functions in source control somewhere.

Comment: Yeah, tried mysqldump with --routines option and solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment above, `mysqldump --routines` is required to include stored procedures, functions, and events in the dump output. This option is not enabled by default, so you have to remember to use it when you dump your database.